# increment within a loop to alter css value doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, zepto

I tried to increment the value of current 'top' property value within a foreach.

http://jsfiddle.net/fqmnksgL/

```
var percent = 50;
$('div').forEach(function (obj, i) {
    $(obj).css('top', $(obj).css('top') + percent);
});
```

Is there anything wrong with my code above?

Comment: `$('div')` returns a HTMLCollection which is not exaclty as Array, as you might be thinking. `forEach` is a Array method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```js
var percent = 50;
$('div').css('top', function(i, obj) {
  return i * percent;
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`forEach` is part of `Array`. Use `each` instead. You can use the function callback to increment the `top` property of the current element.

```
var percent = 50;
$('div').each(function() {
    $(this).css('top', function(_, top){ 
        return parseInt(top, 10) + percent;
    });
});
```

But it doesn't work as you intended. Perhaps you should try something like the other answer, which uses `$.fn.prev`

Comment: Your answer was way better than mine, but I have two questions. 1) Can't `top` be `undefined`? and 2) what is the significance of `(+top)`?

Comment: + converts string to int.

Comment: I tested ur code with the fiddle, it doesn't work http://jsfiddle.net/fqmnksgL/5/

Answer (score 0):

You can't add percent (%) to px value, you need to convert one of them

```
var px = 50;
$('div').each(function () {

    $(this).css('top', parseInt($(this).prev().css('top')) + px);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fqmnksgL/6/